# datetime vs. timestamp in GCP bigquery

Tags: datetime, google-bigquery

I am fairly new to BQ. Few questions about datetime vs. timestamp.
I have a requirement to store all data in bigquery in CST6CDT timezone, such that end users never have to think or question what timezone the data is referring to.

In other words, I want to store the result of following code as is, in a timestamp field with no TZ reference.

## standardSQL

SELECT CURRENT_DATETIME('CST6CDT')

Result in console: 2019-07-31T17:09:37.074268

Now I want to do 2 things:

a) get rid of the letter T from the result
b) store "2019-07-31 17:09:37.074268" in a timestamp field such that when I read from it, I get the same result, not the result converted to UTC

In fact, I thought of NOT using timestamp column type anywhere in BQ. But,  partitioning doesn't work on datetime fields and demands a timestamp field.

In other words, I want bq timestamp to behave(read and write) like all other major databases in the world.

Comment: how about `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`?

Comment: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()  is always in UTC. I need the equivalent of TIMESTAMP without timezone

Comment: it might be just me  - but I still not sure what the question is  - you may want to provide more/better example(s) of what exactly you need/have

Comment: TIMESTAMP haas a timezone. Period. Now you can convert your current time such that it stores it as a UTC. So when it is stored, it's incorrect (technically) but you get the correct value. But it seems incorrect whatever you are trying to achieve by this.
Try:
`select TIMESTAMP(REPLACE(CAST(CURRENT_DATETIME('CST6CDT') as STRING),"T",""))`


I would recommend using this generally:
`SELECT extract(datetime from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() at time zone "CST6CDT");`

Comment: Suyash, Thank you for your reply. So, BQ Timestamp in essence doesn't have the concept of "without timezone". It will store any input from any other TZ in UTC. Here is the problem when a business wants to store and retrieve all times in one time zone. It adds the overhead of converting to UTC to write and the same overhead of converting to the desired TZ while reading from it. For our usage scenario I think datetime will be more suitable and we have to add a new column of date data type, for the tables that needs to be partitioned. Thank you for helping me understand.